# MongoDb: Loading documents with pagination reloads some documents again in multiple pages

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have this model.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const LoungeSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    public_or_private: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["PUBLIC", "PRIVATE"],
    },
  },

  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = Channel = mongoose.model("lounge", LoungeSchema);
```

I am trying to load the corresponding documents in the app with pagination:

```
const TEST_getXNumberOfPublicLounges =
  async function TEST_getXNumberOfPublicLounges(page, results_per_page) {
    results_per_page = parseInt(results_per_page);
    const search_option = {
      public_or_private: "PUBLIC",
    };

    const x_number_of_public_lounges = await Lounge.find(search_option)
      .and(search_option)
      .select("_id")
      .sort({ updatedAt: -1 })
      .limit(results_per_page)
      .skip(results_per_page * page)
      .lean();

    return x_number_of_public_lounges;
  };
```

The problem is that I noticed it **randomly** loads some lounges again in different pages. So a single lounge can be present in page 1 and some other pages when it should be only present in 1 page.

I wrote this function to save the results of pagination:

```
function saveQueryResult(page, resultsPerPage, response) {
  const queryData = {
    page: page,
    resultsPerPage: resultsPerPage,
    response: response,
  };

  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "./query_logs.json");

  fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (readErr, data) => {
    if (readErr && readErr.code === "ENOENT") {
      // If the file doesn't exist, create it and write the initial data
      const initialData = [queryData];
      fs.writeFile(
        filePath,
        JSON.stringify(initialData, null, 2),
        (writeErr) => {
          if (writeErr) {
            console.error("Error creating query log file:", writeErr);
          } else {
            console.log("Query log file created and initial data written.");
          }
        }
      );
      return;
    } else if (readErr) {
      console.error("Error reading query log file:", readErr);
      return;
    }

    let logData = [];
    if (data) {
      logData = JSON.parse(data);
    }

    logData.push(queryData);

    fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(logData, null, 2), (writeErr) => {
      if (writeErr) {
        console.error("Error writing to query log file:", writeErr);
      } else {
        console.log("Query data written to log file.");
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I called that function for the first five pages like this:

```
// I replaced this with 0 then 1 then 2 ...etc
// Using a for loop messes up the saveQueryResult function output
const page = ;
const results_per_page = 10;
loungeServices
  .TEST_getXNumberOfPublicLounges(page, results_per_page)
  .then((lounges) => {
    saveQueryResult(page, results_per_page, lounges); // Save the query details
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(" ~ file: lounges.js:634 ~ err:", err);
  });
```

The result is a file **query_logs.json** that contains the query result for each page:

```
[
  {
    "page": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 10,
    "response": [
      {
        "_id": "648ab84867d05665ffc2117f"
      },
      {
        "_id": "64dd60818079a179971b1fd3"
      },
      {
        "_id": "60d1c995908d5c48ec65133a"
      },
      {
        "_id": "62c45a6a9230157494e12c48"
      },
      {
        "_id": "64a1b856a242ee5767575efd"
      },
      {
        "_id": "63dea082efd62a74666a8888"
      },
      {
        "_id": "615d9428bcf3383e74aeb15c"
      },
      {
        "_id": "64e36678bda58470fe2b62d4"
      },
      {
        "_id": "636ade5585c11d02eaac8197"
      },
      {
        "_id": "636ade9685c11d02eaac81d0"
      }
    ]
  },
  // The other pages next
```

Then I wrote this function to search for duplicate lounges by their ids:

```
function findAndWriteDuplicateIds() {
  try {
    console.log('Reading query_logs.json...');
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('query_logs.json', 'utf-8'));
    console.log('JSON data loaded successfully.');

    const idMap = new Map();
    const duplicates = [];

    jsonData.forEach(page => {
      const response = page.response;
      response.forEach(item => {
        const id = item._id;
        if (idMap.has(id)) {
          console.log(`Found duplicate ID: ${id}`);
          duplicates.push({
            id,
            page: page.page,
            conflictingPage: idMap.get(id)
          });
        } else {
          idMap.set(id, page.page);
        }
      });
    });

    if (duplicates.length > 0) {
      console.log(`Found ${duplicates.length} duplicate IDs.`);
      const duplicateIdsJson = JSON.stringify(duplicates, null, 2);

      fs.writeFileSync('duplicate_ids.json', duplicateIdsJson);
      console.log('Duplicate IDs written to duplicate_ids.json');
    } else {
      console.log('No duplicate IDs found.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', error);
  }
}
```

And this results in a file duplicate_ids.json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "636ade5585c11d02eaac8197",
    "page": 1,
    "conflictingPage": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "64023a8f8b49e477c7eecacf",
    "page": 2,
    "conflictingPage": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "64023a918b49e477c7eecae0",
    "page": 2,
    "conflictingPage": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "64083b90f85e634eebeb2d0c",
    "page": 2,
    "conflictingPage": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "6426d2c69046017fd9b94dec",
    "page": 3,
    "conflictingPage": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "64498c8535c3a43eb61ad1ba",
    "page": 3,
    "conflictingPage": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "64083b90f85e634eebeb2d0c",
    "page": 3,
    "conflictingPage": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "64498cf135c3a43eb61ad22f",
    "page": 3,
    "conflictingPage": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "63a8190b66efd215ff7f7894",
    "page": 3,
    "conflictingPage": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "64083b91f85e634eebeb2d13",
    "page": 3,
    "conflictingPage": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "614af4b42b12bd11ef121d6c",
    "page": 4,
    "conflictingPage": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "6429800e1e3b9e324b9c3523",
    "page": 4,
    "conflictingPage": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "63a8190b66efd215ff7f7894",
    "page": 4,
    "conflictingPage": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "64083b91f85e634eebeb2d13",
    "page": 4,
    "conflictingPage": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "64083b98f85e634eebeb2d4d",
    "page": 4,
    "conflictingPage": 3
  },
  {
    "id": "640ce13c3189be2ca87258f8",
    "page": 4,
    "conflictingPage": 3
  }
]
```

As you see all of those are lounges that have been loaded in more than 1 page.
Any idea why is this happening?

---

**EDIT 1:**
I noticed when I comment out the sort stage the issue stops happening:

```
const TEST_getXNumberOfPublicLounges =
  async function TEST_getXNumberOfPublicLounges(page, results_per_page) {
    results_per_page = parseInt(results_per_page);
    const search_option = {
      public_or_private: "PUBLIC",
    };

    const x_number_of_public_lounges = await Lounge.find(search_option)
      .and(search_option)
      .select("_id")
      // .sort({ updatedAt: -1 })
      .limit(results_per_page)
      .skip(results_per_page * page)
      .lean();

    return x_number_of_public_lounges;
  };
```

But, the sort stage is needed for the logic of the app.

Comment: docs say .and should get array of conditions. does that change anything. also skip before limit